# Can I Embed a Custom Video Player with Local Videos in Google Sites?

Tags: javascript, html, embed, google-sites

I have added a html file through Embed tag in Google Sites. This is a custom video player. I used `<video>` tag to add video into the page but in case of google sites there is no file manager system, you know. That's why I can't locate the video file in there.
Is there any way to add local videos (of course uploaded on google drive or directly on the site page <I don't know whether it is possible or not>)?

I have also tried youtube's video url in `src` attribute. And simply didn't work. I was expecting that the two players will overlay. In case of testing on my localpc chrome's default video player and my video player overlayed.

**THE CODE Only (sorry for the mess. one file embed is supported there so i bring all the three files- .html, .css, .js together.)**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Megaplex</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- These 3 links are only for icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Rounded:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<style>
/* Import Google font - Poppins */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
}
body, .container, .video-controls, .video-timer, .options{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container{
  width: 98%;
  user-select: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 900px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #000;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.container.fullscreen{
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: -15px;
  transition: all 0.08s ease;
}
.container.show-controls .wrapper{
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 0.13s ease;
}
.wrapper::before{
  content: "";
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(100% + 35px);
  pointer-events: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), transparent);
}
.video-timeline{
  height: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.video-timeline .progress-area{
  height: 3px;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
.progress-area span{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -25px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.progress-area .progress-bar{
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #2289ff;
}
.progress-bar::before{
  content: "";
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2289ff;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.progress-bar::before, .progress-area span{
  display: none;
}
.video-timeline:hover .progress-bar::before,
.video-timeline:hover .progress-area span{
  display: block;
}
.wrapper .video-controls{
  padding: 5px 20px 10px;
}
.video-controls .options{
  width: 100%;
}
.video-controls .options:first-child{
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.video-controls .options:last-child{
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.options button{
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  font-size: 19px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  color: #efefef;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.options button :where(i, span) {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.options button:hover :where(i, span){
  color: #fff;
}
.options button:active :where(i, span){
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
.options button span{
  font-size: 23px;
}
.options input{
  height: 4px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  max-width: 75px;
  accent-color: #0078FF;
}
.options .video-timer{
  color: #efefef;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.video-timer .separator{
  margin: 0 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Open sans";
}
.playback-content{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.playback-content .speed-options{
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  left: -40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  width: 95px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: opacity 0.13s ease;
}
.playback-content .speed-options.show{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.speed-options li{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 15px;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}
.speed-options li:where(:first-child, :last-child){
  margin: 0px;
}
.speed-options li:hover{
  background: #dfdfdf;
}
.speed-options li.active{
  color: #fff;
  background: #3e97fd;
}
.container video{
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .wrapper .video-controls{
    padding: 3px 10px 7px;
  }
  .options input, .progress-area span{
    display: none!important;
  }
  .options button{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  .options .video-timer{
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  .video-timer .separator{
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 2px;
  }
  .options button :where(i, span) {
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .options button span{
    font-size: 21px;
  }
  .options .video-timer, .progress-area span, .speed-options li{
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .playback-content .speed-options{
    width: 75px;
    left: -30px;
    bottom: 30px;
  }
  .speed-options li{
    margin: 1px 0;
    padding: 3px 0 3px 10px;
  }
  .right .pic-in-pic{
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container show-controls">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="video-timeline">
            </div>
            <ul class="video-controls">
                <li class="options left">
                    <button class="volume"><i class="fa-solid fa-volume-high"></i></button>
                    <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="any">
                    <div class="video-timer">
                        <p class="current-time">00:00</p>
                        <p class="separator"> / </p>
                        <p class="video-duration">00:00</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="options center">
                    <button class="play-pause"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
                </li>
                <li class="options right">
                    <div class="playback-content">
                        <button class="playback-speed"><span class="material-symbols-rounded">slow_motion_video</span></button>
                        <ul class="speed-options">
                            <li data-speed="2">2x</li>
                            <li data-speed="1.5">1.5x</li>
                            <li data-speed="1" class="active">Normal</li>
                            <li data-speed="0.75">0.75x</li>
                            <li data-speed="0.5">0.5x</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <button class="pic-in-pic"><span class="material-icons">picture_in_picture_alt</span></button>
                    <button class="fullscreen"><i class="fa-solid fa-expand"></i></button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <video src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3sDfsZboq3Y" oncontextmenu="return false;"></video>
    </div>

<script>
const container = document.querySelector(".container"),
mainVideo = container.querySelector("video"),
videoTimeline = container.querySelector(".video-timeline"),
progressBar = container.querySelector(".progress-bar"),
volumeBtn = container.querySelector(".volume i"),
volumeSlider = container.querySelector(".left input");
currentVidTime = container.querySelector(".current-time"),
videoDuration = container.querySelector(".video-duration"),
playPauseBtn = container.querySelector(".play-pause i"),
speedBtn = container.querySelector(".playback-speed span"),
speedOptions = container.querySelector(".speed-options"),
pipBtn = container.querySelector(".pic-in-pic span"),
fullScreenBtn = container.querySelector(".fullscreen i");
let timer;

const hideControls = () => {
    if(mainVideo.paused) return;
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
        container.classList.remove("show-controls");
    }, 2000);
}
hideControls();

container.addEventListener("mousemove", () => {
    container.classList.add("show-controls");
    clearTimeout(timer);
    hideControls();   
});

const formatTime = time => {
    let seconds = Math.floor(time % 60),
    minutes = Math.floor(time / 60) % 60,
    hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);

    seconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes;
    hours = hours < 10 ? `0${hours}` : hours;

    if(hours == 0) {
        return `${minutes}:${seconds}`
    }
    return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

videoTimeline.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
    let timelineWidth = videoTimeline.clientWidth;
    let offsetX = e.offsetX;
    let percent = Math.floor((offsetX / timelineWidth) * mainVideo.duration);
    const progressTime = videoTimeline.querySelector("span");
    offsetX = offsetX < 20 ? 20 : (offsetX > timelineWidth - 20) ? timelineWidth - 20 : offsetX;
    progressTime.style.left = `${offsetX}px`;
    progressTime.innerText = formatTime(percent);
});

videoTimeline.addEventListener("click", e => {
    let timelineWidth = videoTimeline.clientWidth;
    mainVideo.currentTime = (e.offsetX / timelineWidth) * mainVideo.duration;
});

mainVideo.addEventListener("timeupdate", e => {
    let {currentTime, duration} = e.target;
    let percent = (currentTime / duration) * 100;
    progressBar.style.width = `${percent}%`;
    currentVidTime.innerText = formatTime(currentTime);
});

mainVideo.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {
    videoDuration.innerText = formatTime(mainVideo.duration);
});

const draggableProgressBar = e => {
    let timelineWidth = videoTimeline.clientWidth;
    progressBar.style.width = `${e.offsetX}px`;
    mainVideo.currentTime = (e.offsetX / timelineWidth) * mainVideo.duration;
    currentVidTime.innerText = formatTime(mainVideo.currentTime);
}

volumeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(!volumeBtn.classList.contains("fa-volume-high")) {
        mainVideo.volume = 0.5;
        volumeBtn.classList.replace("fa-volume-xmark", "fa-volume-high");
    } else {
        mainVideo.volume = 0.0;
        volumeBtn.classList.replace("fa-volume-high", "fa-volume-xmark");
    }
    volumeSlider.value = mainVideo.volume;
});

volumeSlider.addEventListener("input", e => {
    mainVideo.volume = e.target.value;
    if(e.target.value == 0) {
        return volumeBtn.classList.replace("fa-volume-high", "fa-volume-xmark");
    }
    volumeBtn.classList.replace("fa-volume-xmark", "fa-volume-high");
});

speedOptions.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(option => {
    option.addEventListener("click", () => {
        mainVideo.playbackRate = option.dataset.speed;
        speedOptions.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
        option.classList.add("active");
    });
});

document.addEventListener("click", e => {
    if(e.target.tagName !== "SPAN" || e.target.className !== "material-symbols-rounded") {
        speedOptions.classList.remove("show");
    }
});

fullScreenBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    container.classList.toggle("fullscreen");
    if(document.fullscreenElement) {
        fullScreenBtn.classList.replace("fa-compress", "fa-expand");
        return document.exitFullscreen();
    }
    fullScreenBtn.classList.replace("fa-expand", "fa-compress");
    container.requestFullscreen();
});

speedBtn.addEventListener("click", () => speedOptions.classList.toggle("show"));
pipBtn.addEventListener("click", () => mainVideo.requestPictureInPicture());
mainVideo.addEventListener("play", () => playPauseBtn.classList.replace("fa-play", "fa-pause"));
mainVideo.addEventListener("pause", () => playPauseBtn.classList.replace("fa-pause", "fa-play"));
playPauseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => mainVideo.paused ? mainVideo.play() : mainVideo.pause());
videoTimeline.addEventListener("mousedown", () => videoTimeline.addEventListener("mousemove", draggableProgressBar));
document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => videoTimeline.removeEventListener("mousemove", draggableProgressBar));
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ok i am editing the question.